# Is there a way to add a link directly into this media query?

Tags: query, media

I am running this query which pulls all of the images attached to a particular post and outputs them into a slideshow (See example here - http://powers.deanelliott.me/property/1428-elm-street/)

Is there a way that I can directly output a link (So that the larger image gets displayed in a lightbox) into this query as adding link tags doesn't seem to work

```
<?php $args = array('numberposts' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'post_parent' => $post->ID); ?>
    <?php if ( $photos = get_posts($args) ) : ?>
        <?php foreach ( $photos as $photo ) : ?>
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID,'thumbnail'); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `the_attachment_link` or `wp_get_attachment_link`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_attachment_link

**Example**

```
the_attachment_link( $photo->ID, false, false, true );
```

Comment: How would I include that in the original query though without having to use `<a href="#"></a>` which is where the problem lies